# Integral Domain but not a UFD

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, unique-factorization-domains

Let $R = \mathbb{Z}[x,y]$. Find ideals $I$ such that.

1. $R/I$ is an integral domain but not a UFD
2. The polynomial $z^2 - 1$ has more than two roots in $R/I$.

---

For 1, I have $I = (x^2 - xy -1)$ which I think is irreducible and so far can't show why. Then in $R/I$, $xy = (x-1)(x+1)$.

These solutions don't 'feel' right.

Comment: What does $z=1,x,$ and $z^2-1$ in $R/I$ mean? You want to find three elements of $R/I$ which are roots of $z^2-1$. $z$ is a variable, not an element of $R/I$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews My bad, I meant if $z = -1, 1$ or $x$. Then $z^2 -1 = 0$ in $R/I$

Comment: So, $x^2-1$ is divisible by $x^2+1$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Ah!, what I wrote is complete garbage. As of now, I still can't figure it out. PS. I've also deleted the garbage I wrote.

Comment: I thought you wanted it such that $x+I$ satisfied the equation $z^2-1$ as well as $1+I$ and $-1+I$? I think that works if you just choose the ideal so that this happens.

Comment: @user1537366 So $I = (x^2 - 1)$ for part (2)?

Comment: I thought so, but I might be wrong... ask @ThomasAndrews

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Does $I = (x^2-1)$ for part (2) sound right?

Comment: For part (1), I think you can express it as $-xy+x^2-1$ and then $x+1$ is prime and $x+1\mid x^2-1$, $(x+1)^2\nmid x^2-1$, and $x+1\nmid -x$? I'm sorry I am weak at abstract algebra...

Comment: @SpamIAm no. $\mathbb Z[X,Y]$ is still a UFD (any polynomial ring in finitely many variables over a UFD is a UFD).

Comment: @kahen Oh, whoops I thought it said PID!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Let $I=(3,x^2+y^2-1)$. Then $R/I\simeq(\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z)[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1)$.
2. Let $I=(3,x^2-1)$. There are at least three roots of $z^2-1$ in $R/I$: $1,2$, and $x\bmod I$.

Comment: For 1, Is it true because $2 = 2 \cdot 1 = 2 \cdot (x^2 + y^2)$? Thus also $I = (3, (x + y)^2 - 1)$ could work. i.e $2 = 2 \cdot 2 = (x + y) \cdot (x+y)$?

Comment: @algor207 No: $2$ is invertible in $R/I$. It works for $y^2=(x-1)(x+1)$.

Comment: Why didn't the OP's idea for (1) work then?

Comment: @user1537366 For this: $x(x-y)=1$.